# WSSE Security Soap Header web service request returning response properly in SOAP UI but throwing exception in Java program

Tags: java, soap, websphere, cxf, wsse

I got a servlet running in websphere. I am on the client's end.. I got to call a Apache CXF web service which expects a encrypted user id and password in soap header...it requires usage of WSSE Security Header..Now this request is working when fired in SOAP UI. But throwing security exception in Java.. I am putting in the SOAP Request and Exception here.. What am I missing? I googled and found little help

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="EXTSYSTEMSADMIN">
    <wsse:Username>lZvdO0sQNLqlxfDe4jUzgg==</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">za/jVwHhQROvEnGvXQHsOIbUiSdP3ZBrJXio6gQqMeU=</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
.......    
</soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the stack trace...

```
servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet xxxx in application XXX. Exception created : javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1310)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1036)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:558)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:473)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:436)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:351)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:159)
      at $Proxy45.getDataFromClarity(Unknown Source)
      at legal.vzwcorp.com.TestWS.doGet(TestWS.java:116)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
      at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

Comment: I haven't used CXF before but I have used this trace setting to print out SOAP requests and responses to help debug. com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all. Have you configured any security settings for JAX-WS client in WAS or are you building the whole SOAP envelope yourself? I'll also offer you this for some more debugging help. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_adams/0803_adams.html

Comment: +1 @Nick for helping..I shall check this out and get back

Comment: Check if your raw request from soapUI and the java program is the same! sometimes they generate wsse headers differently, for example nonce and timestamp tags might be different.